# Google Sheets Notifications When Cell is Edited?

Tags: notifications, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I would like to have send an e-mail to a specified user whenever a particular cell is edited. So, for example, the trigger column is column J. My goal is that when a cell (J4, for example) is edited, it will send an automatic e-mail to the e-mail address that is provided in cell A4. I know this will require a script.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Well, this is for an existing spreadsheet. That's about as far as I've gotten. I haven't written a script, but from what I've seen from searching around, its seems theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
function onEditTrigger(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var intCol = range.getColumn();

  if (intCol == 10)                                           // Check for column J
  {
    var intRow = range.getRow();                              // Get the row number of the edited cell
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(intRow, 1, 1, 3);          // Select columns A to C on the same row as the edited cell
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();                   // Get the values in the selected range and store them in the dataValues array

    MailApp.sendEmail(dataValues[0][0], "Notification", "Value in column C: " + dataValues[0][2]); // dataValues[0][0] = e-mail address, dataValues[0][2] = additional information
  }
}
```

Then manually set the trigger to `onEdit` on the Resources menu of the Script Editor.

The script is pretty much self-explanatory as I put some comments there. But basically, the script first checks if a user edited the "trigger" column. If it is the "trigger" column, it gets the row number of that edited cell and gets the corresponding e-mail address in column A, and the additional information in column C of the same row. A notification e-mail is then sent to that e-mail address with the subject "Notification" and the value in column C as the body of the e-mail message.

Comment: Awesome man, I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Now, what if I wanted to add one more piece of information? For example, I'd like to include the value of the associated cell in column c to the text of the e-mail. Is that possible? So, cell J4 is edited, which triggers the e-mail to the address in cell A4 and that e-mail includes the value from cell C4.

Comment: @JaysonDeMar I updated the code and included the value in column C

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Works Perfect. Thanks again for the help.