# Google Sheet notification when a cell in a particular column is edited

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, notifications

I have google sheet where i would like to have an email notification been sent to a specified user whenever a cell in particular column has been edited.

The sheets contains 15 columns and one of the column is for comments and another for email address.

My requirement is whenever any cells in the comment column is edited, I would like to have an email sent to email address mentioned in a different column of the same sheet.

I did went over few of thread and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778653/google-sheets-notifications-when-cell-is-edited) had similar problem and has been successfully answered with a code. However, when i used this script it gives a  a "Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 2, file "Code")" message.

I'm a noob to coding and not sure what does that means.

I also tried [Magic Cell Notification](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/search/Magic%20Cell%20Notifications) addon but to no avail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Send Email**

1. You need to create an installable trigger for `onMyEdit`.
2. You need to provide the sheet name, the emailColumn, the commentColumn, the startingRow for data, the and the subject.
3. And please realize that you can't call this function from the script editor as it requires the event block from the onedit trigger.

`

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Your Sheet Name')return;
  var emailColumn=1;//you have to tell me what column the email is on
  var commentColumn=2;//you have to tell me what column the comment is on
  var startingRow=2;//you have to tell me what row the data starts on
  var subject='You tell me what the subject is';
  if(e.range.columnStart==emailColumn && e.range.rowStart>startingRow && e.value) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,emailColumn).getValue(), subject, sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,commentColumn));
  }
}
```